Cholov Yisroel preferences?
B"H
Some communities have customs to only eat meat, even if it's totally kosher, from certain butchers/companies that follow certain extra guidelines.
For example, some Lubavitchers only eat meat slaughtered by another "Lubavitcher" (one who goes to mikveh and learns chitas and chassidus), even though they agree that other meat is totally kosher
Are there any similar customs for any communities for the practice of consuming cholov Yisroel dairy products?
Are there different standards within cholov Yisroel itself, at least according to any (Orthodox/Torah observant) Jewish communities nowadays, or does everyone who keeps cholov Yisroel agree with all cholov Yisroel products from all of their companies?

I know people in Israel who will only consume "Mehadrin" cholov yisrael, which among other things excludes milk produced on Shabbat

Putting this in a comment rather than an answer to minimise machloket I have no doubt that there are different standards of reliance within Chalav Yisrael as in other areas. The KLBD (Kashrut Division of the London Beth Din) https://www.kosher.org.uk/article/klbd-about-us requires that dairy bakeries, caterers and restaurants under its supervision use only Chalav Yisrael milk and cheese products nevertheless many chareidim in London do not recognise KLBD kashrut, recognising only Kedassia https://www.vaad.org/england/kedassia-the-joint-kashrus-committee-of-england/

See more here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2676/21 Still, we are ultimately talking far less halachic complexity than shechitah, and a derabanan rather than a deorasya.

FWIW, I once saw a CH"Y milk container with hechsherim from CHK (Lubavitcher), Kiryas Joel (Satmar), and Dayan Eckstein (Belz). This is a true expression of achdus in our people

Some allow video cameras. Some don't

This article from OU Kosher explains what cholov Yisroel means and how facilities operate in order to produce cholov Yisroel.
The possibility of differing standards of supervision is addressed in this section

Basic Cholov Yisroel Requirements
Halacha stipulates that if a milk farm is Jewish-owned, there is no
need for special supervision, even if a gentile does the milking, so
long as there are no non-kosher animals on site and there is no
gentile house interceding between the milking area and the Jewish
residence (or office, in modern times). (Shulchan Aruch, Rama ibid.)
When a farm that has non-kosher species provides milk for Jewish
consumption, there needs to be an on-site mashgiach who is able to
watch the milking at all times (although he can be yotzei v’nichnas,
sporadically entering and leaving, and is not required to actually
watch the milking throughout). A farm that has only kosher animals
needs a mashgiach outside its entrance to prevent non-kosher milk or
animals from entering. Here also, the mashgiach need not be there at
all times; yotzei v’nichnas supervision suffices. In all cases, the
mashgiach must be present before the milking commences in order to
check the milking equipment to ascertain that it has been cleansed of
any residual unsupervised milk. (Remo ibid. and Shach s.k. 8)
Additionally, nearly all Poskim require the mashgiach to be present to
observe the beginning of the actual milking, even if there are no
non-kosher animals at the farm. (Remo ibid., Shach ibid. s.k. 5-6, Taz
ibid. s.k. 4, Chachmat Adam 67:1, Aruch HaShulchan 115:7)
The Shach (ibid.) explains that our reliance on yotzei v’nichnas
supervision is based on the halachic principle of mirtat, which means
that the farmer is afraid to adulterate kosher milk with non-kosher
milk out of fear of being caught in the act by the mashgiach. Thus,
spontaneous in-and-out supervision suffices.


Interesting, from personal encounters I always thought the mashgiach is different from the person actually Hired to just watch the milk
