# Can a live video feed remove the prohibition of Yichud?

Tags: halacha, yichud-seclusion, see-sight-vision-blind, technology

I was wondering if and how a public videostream could affect a potential yichud situation.  For example, may a single guy and girl be secluded if they set up a continuously broadcasting camera and send a link to the video feed to a couple of their trustworthy friends?

Comment: Moishe, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking register/login, above.

Comment: This question is a special case of http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/1482/in-a-room-watched-by-cameras, but I don't want to close it, because it focuses in on an important case which deserves its own answers.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers!
I thought that being behind a locked door IS yichud -- even though people might come by. And if so (that it not yichud with the door unlocked, but is yichud with the door locked), then tzvi's question is still unresolved: Aren't there many non-yichud situations that can become yichud with just a small change?  and if so, is the yichud cam really any different?

Answer (score 10):

> There are those who say that if the
>   office is monitored by closed circuit
>   television and the monitors are in a
>   different room than the people in
>   Yichud, then there is no Yichud
>   problem. (Minchas Ish 20:8)
>
> As regards closed circuit television
>   cameras being a mitigating factor in a
>   Yichud situation, see [Nitei Gavriel
>   45:8,9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46544&pgnum=295).

http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/the-laws-of-yichud/10.htm

Comment: I think there's quite a difference between a webcam (in question) that can be accessed by anyone at anytime, and a cctv where one needs access to the monitors...

Comment: well based on what you are saying - if a cctv is OK as per sources above than a webcam should be even better!

Comment: @Gershon Gold True. On the other hand, it just occurred to me that most CCTV's are recorded while webcams are simply broadcast. So it's possible that there are times where you can know that no one's watching... [although there's still always a risk]. CYLOR