# Yichud in Elevator

Tags: technology, yichud-seclusion

Is there a problem of Yichud in the elevator?

(especially considering there's a possibility that the elevator may get stuck)

[and specifically [those without cameras](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/check-out-my-yichud-cam)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [this website](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/the-laws-of-yichud/08.htm),

> Some Poskim prohibit Yichud in an elevator. However, the opinion of most Poskim is that it is permitted as long as the elevator may be stopped on any floor by those wishing to enter. This would apply in office and apartment buildings and other public buildings during the day and early hours of the night. However, late at night or very early in the morning, one should be stringent. It is certainly a middas chassidus to avoid Yichud in an elevator wherever possible.

(See the link for sources.)

Comment: What about the possibility that the elevator may get stuck?

Comment: @yydl, One should also bring his tefillin along on elevators in case it gets stuck for the whole day. :)

Comment: @jake I think it's safe to presume that an elevator won't be stuck for that long. But for 5-10 minutes is highly reasonable (until the fire department / repair people get there...).

Comment: @yydl, How probable is it to get stuck in an elevator? Personally, I never have.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.boacalgary.com/artelev2.html), "As for the odds of getting stuck in an elevator. They're about once in a lifetime for the average person using elevators on a daily basis."

Comment: @jake Strange. I personally know at least three instances where the elevator "got stuck" and the occupant was trapped for an amount of time. See [here](http://www.greenspun.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg.tcl?msg_id=002Qbi): "I've been stuck in an elevator plenty of times. Most of the time due to a power outage."

Comment: @yydl, I'm no posek, but I'd say *ones rachmana patrei*.  It's unlikely enough that the elevator will get stuck, that such a situation would be considered a freak accident.

Answer (score 6):

The shiur yichud is longer than an elevator ride, so it shouldn't be a problem.
See this site which has a short discussion of it:
http://koltorah.org/ravj/The%20Yichud%20Prohibition%20-%20Part%202.htm

Comment: This assumes one is permitted to enter into a yichud situation for less than the shiur. Not everyone agrees this is permitted.

Comment: What about the possibility that the elevator may get stuck?

Comment: That doesn't happen very frequently. I don't think you need to worry about such remote possibilities in halacha.