# Laws of yichud in the Soviet Union

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In Soviet Union, is there heter for man and woman to seclude in same room if there is chazaka that KGB is watching?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Serious version: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/can-a-live-video-feed-remove-the-prohibition-of-yichud

Answer (score 6):

There's no worry about *yichud* anyway. [In Soviet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_reversal) Khakassia, [*ir*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8%D1%80#Khakas) is *baalah*!

Answer (score 4):

Russia has had a heter since the late 1980's with the introduction of a policy of glasnost, or openness. The notion of transparency removes concerns that no one is watching.