# Yichud with surveillance cameras

Tags: tznius-modesty

If there is video cameras all over the house and is being recorded,is this considered a problem of yichud or do we say that since they know they are being watched they would never commit a sin?

Comment: Dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5287/3
And dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1482/3

Comment: @WAF Isn't that live whereas this is recorded?

Comment: One of those makes the distinction explicit. The other does not. The answerers seem to all but ignore it, and it is not clear that it has any bearing on the question here. Perhaps a comprehensive answer to any one of the three would address that difference.

Comment: 5287 is a live feed, which seems like it should be different, and the answer there deals with a live feed also. 1482 is about recording like this question but is much more general. That said, the answer there does deal with _yichud_ (albeit briefly and unsourcedly) and this question is a special case of that one, so I agree this should be closed as a duplicate of 1482, @WAF.